# Disconnected graphs in Storm topologies

Tags: apache-storm

Let's assume we have next topology scheme:

```
spout1 -> bolt1.1 -> bolt1.2
spout2 -> bolt2.1 -> bolt2.2
```

and it will be no connections between 1.x bolts and 2.x bolts, so topology graph is disconnected.
Is there any reason to keep this subgraphs in the same topology or is it better to split this graph to separate topologies?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are going to deploy it in different clusters, there is no point to split it into separate topologies (anyway they are going to use the same resources). **There is an advantage by separating it** - For any reason, if one stops working/breaks 2nd one will not have an impact (kind of two parallel processes)